# How to deal with multiple request to server from client

Tags: mysql, database, request, response

I've my messenger app which sends request to server for group creation, server process the request(making a database entry of group) and send back response, but sometimes it happens due to weak connection, response is not received in particular time instant, as a result client sends request again for the same group.

The fault which occurs in this case the server processes both these request and makes two entries (or more in case of more requests) in the database with different group_id for the same group.

> How can I avoid multiple entries in database and make it consistent?
>   Due to multiple entries, when client reinstall app, if there are three entries of a group in database, all three will be loaded in app.

One solution which I thought of is that check if the group with given name already exist, but this is not the accepted solution, since client can create more one group with same name.

Note:

1. I'm using MYSQL Enterprise edition for storing entries on server.
2. You can think of group creation as same as groups are created in WhatsApp messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Packet Id is unique for such repeating JSON requests being sent to server. Use that as a filter and discard the duplicate packet Ids. Same as done with message packets and other requests.